# iptables: is it possible to combine "string" and "mac" modules results?

Tags: linux, dns, iptables, dnsmasq

I have a raspberry pi running dnsmasq.  I configured all my local devices to use this device to resolve DNS queries.

I like to block certain devices using their MAC address from certain queries.  The below iptables entries work separately, but I like to have both condition met before dropping the request.

Thank you,

iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string  "youtube" -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m mac    --mac-source 00:27:0E:33:4B:B2 -j DROP

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new chain with `iptables -N STRING_MATCHED` and then DROP/ACCEPT the packet

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "youtube" -j STRING_MATCHED
iptables -A STRING_MATCHED -m mac --mac-source 00:27:0E:33:4B:B2 -j DROP
iptables -A STRING_MATCHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also multiple matches can be used in a single rule,

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "youtube" -m mac --mac-source 00:27:0E:33:4B:B2 -j DROP
```